# Create Docker image from existing Ubuntu + App

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker

I installed Moodle (eLearning PHP based app, but it could be any app) locally on Ubuntu and would like to package it as Docker image/container. There were whole bunch of installations and configurations done. I'd like to package all that so that I can deploy to some Docker enabled hosting service, such as Digital Ocean or AWS.

How do I create Docker image?

Do I need to handle networking, ports and Apache configuration for production deployment?

Answer (score 2):

There ara a lot of [Moodle images](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=Moodle&starCount=0) in dockerhub. just use one of them

Comment: Thanks but as I said "it could be any app", I'm more interested in the process than getting Moodle running. I'll change the title to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The process to create docker images is well documented on Docker's documentation site. See: [Build your own images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/)

The idea is simple: You inherit/extend an existing image and make additions to it. This is done in a provisioning file called `Dockerfile`

**Dockerfile Example:**

```
FROM debian:8.4
MAINTAINER John Doe (j.doe@example.com)

# update aptitude
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update

# utilities
RUN apt-get -y install vim git php5.6 apache2
```

In the example above I extend a Debian image, update aptitude and install a series of packages.

A full list of commands available in Dockerfiles is available at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Once your Dockerfile is ready you can build the image using the following command:

```
docker build -t debian/enhanced:8.4 /path/to/Dockerfile
```

Comment: I think this refers to getting a Docker image for Ubuntu first, then doing things on it, then build your own. What I asked though is take any random desktop Ubuntu installation with a bunch of installs on it, and pack it with Docker so you can move it. This is without getting the Ubuntu image to begin with.

Comment: @Ska you cannot do that. You have to start with one of the base images. Docker doesn't allow you to build an image using as source the host.

Comment: @Ska what you can do however is to save a container as an image. This means you have to create a clean ubuntu based container, install/configure everything and commit the container as an image.